# Macro "parameter" name mesh. Can it work? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, macros

```
    // MACROS

#define A_PROPERTY(TYPE, NAME)                      \
    private:                                        \
        TYPE NAME;                                  \
    public:                                         \
        void SetNAME(TYPE theNAME) {NAME=theNAME;}  \
        TYPE GetNAME() {return NAME;}               \
```

I am trying to creat a simple Macro that will take a TYPE and a NAME and will create:

1. Private member of TYPE named NAME
2. Public "getter" method called GetNAME (where NAME is variable...)
3. Public "setter" method called GetNAME (where NAME is variable...)

This is how i'd use it from a class definition:

```
A_PROPERTY(int, Age)
```

The MACRO works, but creates a "getNAME" method instead of "get(whatever I put in NAME)". It seems MACROS don't parse strings and "parameters" together very well. Is there a way to achieve what I want? or should I just have the method as "NAME" with a different signature to differentiate the get and the set?

Comment: That is the most disgusting thing I have ever seen.

Comment: Distasteful perhaps, but at least it's readable...

Comment: I hope I didn't cause you permanent damage, DeadMG...

Comment: Ok, my curiosity overcame my sarcasm - what is so disgusting or distasteful about the above question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Use `##`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation) to stitch tokens.

```
#define A_PROPERTY(TYPE, NAME)                            \
    private:                                              \
        TYPE NAME;                                        \ 
    public:                                               \
        void Set##NAME(TYPE the##NAME) {NAME=the##NAME;}  \
        TYPE Get##NAME() {return NAME;}
```

Comment: aha! That's it. Thanks. That's the glue I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
void SetNAME(TYPE theNAME) {NAME=theNAME;}  
TYPE GetNAME() {return NAME;}
```

This will create same function names for all NAME and TYPE parameters.

I think you want this:

```
void Set##NAME(TYPE the##NAME) {NAME=the##NAME;}  
TYPE Get##NAME() {return NAME;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NAME` isn't really private because you can read and write it via the member functions.  You might as well use a `struct`, or make `NAME` public.

Comment: No, it really **is** private because it's in a `private:` section.  Creating accessors like this is a standard idiom.

Comment: @Richard Standard idiom yes, but if we're building an aggregate - and it looks like it - a `struct` is more appropriate.  This macro approach is nasty on so many levels.  At least use templates.

Comment: I'm curious, why a struct? I already have a class, I just want to easily add a member + accessor methods. Why should I define an external struct?

Comment: @Ron The fact you need this macro suggests you have a lot of members all with read/write accessors.  Also that get/set add no value (e.g. check values, perform further action on set or compute something on get, etc.)  From what I see of your class, it looks like an aggregate of unconnected data values and `struct` is a good fit for this.

Comment: got you, yes. it does make sense.